# Initial MongoDB database creating by nodejs like wordpress & MYSQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've been searching something like wordpress the initial database creating, but didn't get much information from Google.

Are we able to create a MongoDB database via an interactive webpage programmed and served by nodejs? something like below image.

The reason is that, I'd like to create a simple blog, I am wondering if there is a way to create the db just like wordpress does.  If anyone knows, can you please provide a howto example? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can use robomongo.It may be helpful for you because it provide the graphical interface in mongodb.

Comment: In mongodb a new database is created automaticly when you connected to it, to manage db via UI, check these tools: [https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/)